# expect script inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, expect, scp

I am really stumped! 
I DONT WANT TO USE RSA AUTH SO PLEASE ABSTAIN.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the server password" 
read password 
cd /home/mike/ 

# this is included the code below -> 
/usr/bin/expect << EOD
set timeout -1
spawn scp file.txt server.com:/home
expect {
  timeout            { send_user "TIME OUT\n"; exit 1 }
  "*assword: "
}
send "$password\r"
expect {
  "s password: " { send_user "\nIncorrect Password. Login Failed.\n"; exit 1 }
  "100%"
}
sleep 1
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

This works and file.txt gets transferred to the server but I get this warning message ->

```
" line 44: warning: here-document at line 22 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOD')"
```

When I add EOD at the end after 'expect eof' it gives me this error ->

```
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send "exit\r"
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
I am saying again I cant use pubkey auth so please dont suggest that.

Comment: Why are you trying to send "exit" to an `scp` session? Do you do that when you use `scp` directly?

Answer (score 4):

By replacing your last line:

```
expect eof
```

with:

```
EOD
```

I don't get the complaint anymore. Note that you cannot have any tabs (and maybe spaces as well?) before your `EOD` tag (which you defined in your initial `/usr/bin/expect` line.

Comment: No, don't replace: **add** the `EOD` line.

Comment: @julumme Thanks :) I appreciate your help. I had a space before EOD. Dint even think about it.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes there is no need to replace it. :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to script this using `expect`, you can simply use `curl` to copy files to/from a remote host via scp or sftp, and pass the authentication credentials to the curl command like so:

```
curl sftp://remotehost.domain.com/path/to/remote/file --user username:password -o /path/to/local/file
```

Comment: Woahh! Will try this too. Thanks. Got a new thing to learn from you :) thumbs up :)